# Faking write permissions on Linux

Tags: linux, permissions

Is there a way to make a file on GNU/Linux pretend to be changed, so that a write call says it succeeds, but the file remains unmodified? I have tried `sudo chattr +i ./file` and changing the file to the root user and removing write permissions, but these both still return a write failure.

Ideally, behaviour would be like:

```bsh
$ echo "Hello, World!" >> file.txt
$ # something that disallows write permission
$ echo "Changed Data" >> file.txt # return code 0
$ cat file.txt
Hello World!
```

I am on KDE Neon on 20.04

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here. [Edit] the question if there is.

Comment: I agree with @KamilMaciorowski. What problem are you trying to solve that would require this solution?

Comment: I agree with @KamilMaciorowski, but also look at the Linux `fakeroot` command which could do what you may be asking for.

Comment: I have a closed source program that overwrites shader files upon launching that I would like to modify. Upon failing to overwrite any file, the program throws an error.
Edit: I should specify I am trying to do game modding, so also please let me know if this is the incorrect forum for system alterations in a modding context

Comment: Not exactly the answer you are looking for but I wonder if there is a union filesystem that could help you.  If not, you coukd likely write a simple fuse filesystem to do this.